# Will Linking or referencing in multiples of the same rig be a feature in 2.8 (re depGraph)?

Tags: rigging, linked-data

I love blender for just about everything animation related including blender pipelines....however one thing that really is frustrating is how you cannot link in the same rig multiple times. I've looked through the dependency graph proposal update for 2.8 and some makes sense but still a bit complex for me to fully grasp what's going on, so question for some smarty out there, will this fix this issue? From a big production point of view this is a must to have!

Comment: You should try to ask developers through specific channles, imho. See options in this page: https://www.blender.org/get-involved/developers/

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer, and its exciting :)

Question to sergey re the dep graph proposal for 2.8

> 2. can this make linking x times one asset possible, each having own animation ? (character with armature)
>
> Yes, that’s the idea. Even more, each of the characters could be customized by overrides, so you create varieties of characters in the same scene.

Source (comment section)
https://code.blender.org/2016/12/dependency-graph-proposal/